# Is the delta module injective?

Tags: modules, homological-algebra, injective-module, d-modules

Is $M=\mathbb{C}[\partial_x,\partial_y]$ an injective $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ module? The action is given by differentiation (swapping the role of $x$ and $\partial_x$). It is injective in the one variable case as the not finitely generated $M$ is always divisible and we are in the PID case. But I don’t know the answer when the number of variable is greater than 1.

Comment: How do $x$ and $y$ act on $\partial_x$ and $\partial_y$ here?

Comment: @ Pedro Tamaroff, sorry i should have made it more clear. For example, say $x^2\cdot \partial_x^3$, then 'think this as $\partial_x^2\cdot x^3$, which is $6x$', so the result will be $6\partial_x$. This action is a bit like the one acting on $\mathbb{C}[x^{-1},y^{-1}]$ (upto coefficients).

Comment: You should probably change your notation, that's a bit confusing. But since you're in zero characteristic, changing the basis for $x^n/n!=e_n$ and $y^n/n! = f_n$ then you're acting by shifts: $d_x(e_n) = e_{n-1}, d_y(e_n) = 0$, and $d_y(f_n) = f_{n-1}, d_x(f_n) = 0$. Perhaps this helps you.